# Mechanical Dream rules gathered together

Tags: mechanical-dream

A while ago I stumbled upon Mechanical Dream. While I found it rather interesting, my group at the time was not so keen on playing, and we rejected it. Since I liked it a lot, I am asking if there is any document, PDF or website with the game's rules gathered and woven in a fashion that is relatively easy to understand. It consists of two core books: one that seems to be a (pretty confusing) rulebook and another one that's more roleplay oriented and introduces some basic ideas that seem to be a big part of the game.

Answer (score 5):

The core Mechanical Dream rule book [*Mechanical Book*](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/112440/Mechanical-Dream-Mechanical-Book) is back in print in PDF from SteamLogic on DriveThruRPG.

The [*Dream Book*](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/112438/Mechanical-Dream-Dream-Book) PDF is also available there.

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google search revealed a few reviews but no web sites dedicated to the game itself. As the game is out-of-print and SteamLogic, the publisher, went bankrupt in 2004, the chances of finding it are pretty slim.

There is a boxed set available on Amazon.com but it's priced at $200.

So the answer to your question "are the game rules available" would, unfortunately, be "no it appears they are not".